# Select function with Map_only Hadoop on java

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, csv, hadoop

I want to create simple function to select the not null tuple in CSV file.
I had considered as input : each line of CSV file, and the value recieve the same tuple if it's not null.
my program is as follow:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class Selectfunction {
    public static  class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>{

        // Map void
        public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            //input   
            Text cle = new Text();
            //int valeur1 = 0;
            //int valeur2 = 1;

             String[] tokens = value.toString().split(","); 
             String cle1 = tokens.toString(); 

             for (int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++) {
                // System.out.println("hana");
                if(tokens[5].toString().equals(null)){

                    value.set(value);
                }
                cle.set(cle1);
                //output.collect(word, one);
                output.collect(new Text(cle), value);
             }  

        }     

    }
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception 
      { 
        if(args.length!=2){
            System.err.println("Usage: WeatherTemperature  <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        // Create a new JobConf
         JobConf job = new JobConf(new Configuration(), Selectfunction.class);

         // Specify various job-specific parameters     
         job.setJobName("myjob");

         FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
         job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
         job.setMapperClass(Selectfunction.Map.class);

        job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class); 
         FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
         JobClient.runJob(job);
      }
       }
```

I have received the following error:

```
16/05/25 23:32:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1448020964278_0451
16/05/25 23:32:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1448020964278_0451 running in uber mode : false
16/05/25 23:32:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/05/25 23:32:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1448020964278_0451_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
        at select.Selectfunction$Map.map(Selectfunction.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

16/05/25 23:32:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1448020964278_0451_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
        at select.Selectfunction$Map.map(Selectfunction.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using TextInputFormat and the RecordReader it uses returns you LongWritable as key and Text as value. That is the reason you are getting above exception. Please refer [this documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html).

Changing your method signature to "public void map(LongWritabe key, Text value, OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException" may help you get around this.

-Amit

Comment: thank you @Amit, that resolve the error of `org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text` and I've an error of configuration:
 `Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)`